# How to change coordinates while converting imagemap to svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, imagemap

I want to convert image map to svg as image map does not resize on browser size change.
how do i  change the coordinates and tags?

```html
<img id="image" src="ch01ch01.png" width="453" height="453" usemap="#map"/>
        <map name="map" id="id_1">
   <area class="notbutton" shape="poly" id=12 coords="172,227,181,224,183,213,189,201,195,193,199,190,199,184,126,93,135,93,123,79,103,96,84,117,68,140,58,162,51,186,48,201,47,214,135,219,130,227,148,227,147,225,151,227,149,223,153,227,153,221,156,225,157,214,160,202,166,190,174,179,176,177,174,174,191,176,192,192,189,189,180,200,174,212,172,224,172,227"
   onmouseover=" Display_img(curr_base_id,'12')" onclick="change_BASE_ID('12',this.className)" onmouseout="Display_base_img()"/>

   <area class="notbutton" shape="poly" id=11 coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   onmouseover=" Display_img(curr_base_id,'11')" onclick="change_BASE_ID('11',this.className)" onmouseout="Display_base_img()"/>
</map>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this code for my image. http://jsfiddle.net/32rx6/2/ but my image width n height is not 100%. It is 453*453 so this does not work for me.

Comment: That code is for the image map.  What have you done w.r.t. SVG?

Comment: tml>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" src="ch01ch01.png">
 
 <path id="ab" d="M 172,227,181,224,183,213,189,201,195,193,199,190,199,184,126,93,135,93,123,79,103,96,84,117,68,140,58,162,51,186,48,201,47,214,135,219,130,227,148,227,147,225,151,227,149,223,153,227,153,221,156,225,157,214,160,202,166,190,174,179,176,177,174,174,191,176,192,192,189,189,180,200,174,212,172,224,172,227"/>


…
</svg>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to your map...

```html
<img id="imageMaps" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWffP.jpg" usemap="#20Keys" width="604" height="604" alt="Select Key" border="0"/>
  <map id="20Keys" name="20Keys">
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 1" title="" coords="41,54,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 2" title="" coords="41,543,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 3" title="" coords="538,543,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 4" title="" coords="499,293,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 5" title="" coords="484,213,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 6" title="" coords="79,293,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 7" title="" coords="141,145,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 8" title="" coords="483,374,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 9" title="" coords="209,99,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 10" title="" coords="290,504,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 11" title="" coords="289,83,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 12" title="" coords="370,99,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 13" title="" coords="370,488,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 14" title="" coords="95,213,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 15" title="" coords="438,442,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 16" title="" coords="438,145,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 17" title="" coords="95,374,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 18" title="" coords="141,442,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 19" title="" coords="209,488,31" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="circle" alt="Key 20" title="" coords="538,45,31" href="" target="" />
  </map>
```

in the form of a responsive SVG is the following:

```html
<svg id="imageMaps" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 604 604" pointer-events="fill" fill="none">
  <title>Select Key</title>
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWffP.jpg" width="604" height="604"/>
  <a xlink:href="" target="">
    <circle cx="41" cy="54" r="31">
      <title></title>
    </circle>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="" target="">
    <circle cx="41" cy="543" r="31">
      <title></title>
    </circle>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="" target="">
    <circle cx="538" cy="543" r="31">
      <title></title>
    </circle>
  </a>
  <!-- etc -->
</svg>
```

I've only done the first few map circles.

The equivalent of

```
<area shape="poly" coords="..coord pairs here.."/>
```

in SVG is:

```
<polygon points="..coord pairs here.."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same issue myself, and found a killer jQuery plugin that helped **IMMENSELY**:

http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

It dynamically resized and re positioned my image map areas.